# Why we have two nb_insert functions in AODV protocol implementation?

Tags: routes, implementation, network-protocols, ns2, neighbours

We have `nb_insert` in `aodv.cc` an the other one is in `aodv_rtable.h` 
what is the difference between `bhead` and `rt_nblist`?